# ExtJS GridPanel width

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using Ext JS 2.3.0 and have created the search dialog shown below.

[image]

The search results are shown in a GridPanel with a single Name column, but notice that this column does not stretch to fill all the available horizontal space. However, after I perform a search, the column resizes properly (even if no results are returned):

[image]

How can I make the column display correctly when it's shown initially? The relevant code is shown below:

```
FV.FindEntityDialog = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable, {

    constructor: function() {

        var queryTextField = new Ext.form.TextField({
            hideLabel: true,
            width: 275,
            colspan: 2,
        });
        var self = this;

        // the search query panel
        var entitySearchForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            width: '100%',
            frame: true,
            layout:'table',
            layoutConfig: {columns: 3},
            items: [
                queryTextField,
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: locale["dialogSearch.button.search"],
                    handler: function() {
                        var queryString = queryTextField.getValue();
                        self._doSearch(queryString);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        // the search results model and view
        this._searchResultsStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            data: [],
            fields: ['name']
        });

        var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
            {
                id: 'name',
                header: locale['dialogSearch.column.name'],
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }
        ]);

        var selectionModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: false});

        this._searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            title: locale['dialogSearch.results.name'],
            height: 400,
            stripeRows: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            autoExpandColumn: 'name',
            store: this._searchResultsStore,

            colModel: colModel,
            selModel: selectionModel,
            hidden: false,
            buttonAlign: 'center',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: locale["dialogSearch.button.add"],
                    handler: function () {
                        entitySearchWindow.close();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: locale["dialogSearch.button.cancel"],
                    handler: function () {
                        entitySearchWindow.close();
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        // a modal window that contains both the search query and results panels
        var entitySearchWindow = new Ext.Window({
            closable: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: true
            },
            title: locale['dialogSearch.title'],
            items: [entitySearchForm, this._searchResultsPanel]
        });

        entitySearchWindow.show();
    },

    /**
     * Search for an entity that matches the query and update the results panel with a list of matches
     * @param queryString
     */
    _doSearch: function(queryString) {

        def dummyResults = [['foo'], ['bar'], ['baz']];       
        self._searchResultsStore.loadData(dummyResults, false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `autoWidth` from `GridPanel` configuration, because setting `autoWidth:true` means that the browser will manage width based on the element's contents, and that Ext will not manage it at all.

In addition you can try to call `.doLayout(false, true)` on your grid after it was rendered.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same issue you had in an earlier question, the viewConfig is an config item for the grid panel check the [docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/) , so it should be

```
this._searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
        },
  ....other configs you need,
```

To be more precise the viewConfig accepts the `Ext.grid.GridView` configs, feel free to read the docs on that one too.

Otherwise this seems to be the only problem, and i refer the column width, not the gridpanel width. On the gridpanel you have a title and two buttons who doesn't seem to be affected. So i repeat the gridPanel's width is ok, it's the columns width issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `flex: 1` to your GridPanel